# AWS API Gateway Method Authorization

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have domain with aws example.com, currently I have record set so that when user goes to example.com, it serves static website from S3 (done with angular) and backend api (Lambda and API gate way). And I don't have sign in process, as the purpose of site is public facing.

I can use apikey on method to authorize the http call, but I still have to save it in js code somewhere, which I don;t want to do. And I am not sure how IAM role can help me in this scenario.

Is there any way I can let api allow calls from specific domain ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use IAM Role defined for Unauthenticated user in AWS Cognito Federated Identities. The [AWS document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-identity-pools.html) will guide through the process assigning IAM Role to the Unauthenticated user.

Then you can enable "AWS_IAM" Authorizer option in the API Gateway for any specific API's resources.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019244/api-gateway-authentication-with-cognito-federated-identities) has similar approach in implementing the IAM Role - based to access API, in which the implementation is using External Federated Identities (Google) instead of unauthenticated user identities.

Answer (score 0):

There are [a few ways to skin this cat](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/).

The least painful way is likely to be using [AWS Signature V4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html)-- unfortunately, there's no great answer for a site that doesn't have an auth system built in already. Someday they'll let us park API Gateways inside of VPCs, but that day isn't today.